# Get just the HTML tag of a JQuery selection

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery to troubleshoot an intermittent problem. I have a selector, and I want to see the element, just the HTML tag that it grabbed.

For instance, my selector is `($'[id^=superfish-utility--3-accordion]')`. I can use `.outerHTML` and get the match with all of its internals

```
<ul id="superfish-utility--3" class="menu sf-menu sf-utility sf-horizontal sf-style-none nav nav-pills"><li id="utility-menu-link-contentf569d1cf-0a1d-4719-b9c1-d504e38dba38" class="sf-depth-1 menuparent"><a href="" class="sf-depth-1 menuparent">News &amp; events</a><ul>...</ul>
```

But what I want to see in the console log is just `<ul id="superfish-utility--3" class="menu sf-menu sf-utility sf-horizontal sf-style-none nav nav-pills">...</ul>`

How can I get just that?

**Edit** This is my code. Woodrow's answer works for me in the inline environment, but when I try to adapt it to my existing script, I still get the tag with its entire contents:

```
$('[id^=superfish-utility--3]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this)[0]);
```

Comment: `console.log(this);` this already refers to DOM object

Comment: try `$(this).clone().empty().prop('outerHTML')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for? Grabbing the `DOM object` using the jQuery `selector` and `[0]` to get the HTML code itself?

```js
$('[id^=superfish-utility--]').each(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="superfish-utility--3-accordion" class="menu sf-menu sf-utility sf-horizontal sf-style-none nav nav-pills">
  <li id="utility-menu-link-contentf569d1cf-0a1d-4719-b9c1-d504e38dba38" class="sf-depth-1 menuparent"><a href="" class="sf-depth-1 menuparent">Accordion #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="superfish-utility--4-accordion" class="menu sf-menu sf-utility sf-horizontal sf-style-none nav nav-pills">
  <li id="utility-menu-link-contentf569d1cf-0a1d-4719-b9c1-d655638dba39" class="sf-depth-1 menuparent"><a href="" class="sf-depth-1 menuparent">Accordion #4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution works for me in the inline environment here, but I don't get the same behavior when I try to adapt it to my existing script. Can you look at my edits and advise me further?

Comment: I can take a look, but it looks like you are looping through ID selectors, whereas IDs should be unique `$('[id^=superfish-utility--3]')` so does the # 3 change with each ID e.g. `$('[id^=superfish-utility--4]')`

Comment: Updated w/ each loop, if I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: `console.log(this);` is enough

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes, you're correct, if you don't want to reference the object within a jQuery `selector` you can just reference scope of `this`. Updated snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So Woodrow posted an answer that obviously worked in the snippet-runner, so I accepted it.

However, in my environment (JavaScript launched in Drupal 8's jQuery wrapper), I was not able to get it to work the same way. When I log the selected element, I get a browseable object (in both Chrome and Firefox):

[image]

Which is nice for debugging, but I can't copy the string of the element, which is ultimately why I'm logging. But, while looking at the object, I found both `innerHTML()`, which has the guts of the tag, and `outerHTML`, which has the the tags and its guts. So I did this:

```
outer = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
inner = $(this)[0].innerHTML
tag = outer.replace(inner, ' ... ');
console.log(tag);
```

which gives me `<ul id="superfish-utility--3" class="menu sf-menu sf-utility sf-horizontal sf-style-none nav nav-pills"> ... </ul>`, a copyable string.